# Write Urdu language in ACM template

Tags: acm, right-to-left

How can i write Urdu language in ACM Template? Here's the template on [Github](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart) and here it is on
[Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-small-standard-format-template/sksvmbxyfhnw#.WnR9l4hubIU)

Answer (score 4):

## Update with solution not using `bidi` or `babel`

This might actually be your best option given that you just need to insert the occasional Urdu word. It is least intrusive and keeps all fonts the same as the default `acmart` package. It only handles inline Urdu within an English LTR paragraph. With a couple of tweaks, I even made it work on Overleaf (see commented out lines).

```
%\def\normalfont{}% add to compile on Overleaf
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\documentclass[format=acmsmall,review=false,screen=true]{acmart}
\newfontfamily\urdufont{Noto Naskh Arabic}[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu]
\ifxetex
  \TeXXeTstate=1
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\texturdu}{\beginR\urdufont\aftergroup\endR}
\fi
\ifluatex
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\texturdu}{\textdir TRT\urdufont}
\fi
%\let\copyright\textcopyright% add to compile on Overleaf
\begin{document}
\acmJournal{TWEB}
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmDOI{0000001.0000001}
\title{Article Title}
\author{John Doe}
\email{john.doe@example.com}
\begin{abstract}
  Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Article body starts here}
English paragraph with inline Urdu \texturdu{اُردُو} English text.
\end{document}
```

---

## Update with solution not using `bidi` package

Here's a solution using `babel` instead of `bidi`. It works with `xelatex` and `lualatex`, but be careful because `babel`'s bidi support is not mature.

Also, I really doubt the journal is going to like this if you are planning on submitting it...

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall,review=false,screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import=ur]{urdu}
\babelprovide[import=en-US,default]{american}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers=Lining]{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont{sf}{Linux Biolinum O}
\babelfont[urdu]{rm}{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\babelfont[urdu]{sf}{Noto Sans Arabic}
\makeatletter
% fix mweights package bold font selection for using fontspec
\def\bfseries@rm{bx}
\def\bfseries@sf{bx}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\acmJournal{TWEB}
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmDOI{0000001.0000001}
\title{Article Title}
\author{John Doe}
\email{john.doe@example.com}
\begin{abstract}
  Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Article body starts here}

English paragraph with inline Urdu
\foreignlanguage{urdu}{اُردُو}
English text.

Display maths:

\[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sin n\phi \]

Right to left Urdu paragraph with inline English:

\selectlanguage{urdu}

اُردُو \foreignlanguage{american}{English text} اُردُو

\selectlanguage{american}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Original example using `bidi` package (breaks `\maketitle`)

A MWE example of what you want would help, but perhaps this will get you started.

I couldn't get `polyglossia` to work because loading `fontspec` after `fontenc` changes the default encoding and you lose the `libertine` fonts set up in `acmart.cls`. Perhaps there's a way around that and someone else can suggest it. For the moment I have loaded `fontspec` (with the `no-math` option) before `\documentclass` and written custom font changing macros.

Note: I don't know what implications this would have if you are submitting to the journal.

**Update:** I just tested this on Overleaf and I see that it doesn't work due to outdated `bidi` and `fontspec` packages. See at the bottom of the answer for workaround.

```
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\documentclass[format=acmsmall,review=false,screen=true]{acmart}
\newfontfamily\urdufont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu]
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand\texturdu[1]{\RLE{\setnonlatin\urdufont#1}}
\newcommand\textenglish[1]{\LRE{\setlatin\fontencoding{T1}\libertine#1}}
\newenvironment{urdu}{\setRL\setnonlatin\urdufont}{}
\newenvironment{english}{\setLR\setlatin\fontencoding{T1}\libertine}{}
\begin{document}
English paragraph with inline Urdu \texturdu{اُردُو} English text.

Display math:

\[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sin n\phi \]

Right to left Urdu paragraph with inline English:

\begin{urdu}
  اُردُو \textenglish{English text} اُردُو
\end{urdu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Workaround for outdated packages on Overleaf:

```
\def\normalsize{} % Workaround for outdated fontspec on Overleaf
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\documentclass[format=acmsmall,review=false,screen=true]{acmart}
\newfontfamily\urdufont{Noto Naskh Arabic}[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu]
\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter % Start workaround for outdated bidi package on Overleaf
\newcommand{\setnonlatin}{\@Latinfalse}
\newcommand{\setlatin}{\@Latintrue}
\setlatin
\makeatother % End workaround for outdated bidi package on Overleaf
\newcommand\texturdu[1]{\RLE{\setnonlatin\urdufont#1}}
\newcommand\textenglish[1]{\LRE{\setlatin\fontencoding{T1}\libertine#1}}
\newenvironment{urdu}{\setRL\setnonlatin\urdufont}{}
\newenvironment{english}{\setLR\setlatin\fontencoding{T1}\libertine}{}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
English paragraph with inline Urdu \texturdu{اُردُو} English text.

Display math:

\[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sin n\phi \]

Right to left Urdu paragraph with inline English:

\begin{urdu}
  اُردُو \textenglish{English text} اُردُو
\end{urdu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes it is writing Urdu now but the abstract and author information all is disappeared!

Comment: @tayyaba. So it does. Hmm. My guess is this is an incompatibility between `bidi` and `acmart`. How much Urdu do you need? Just a little in a mainly English document? Or lots in including document structure? Do you have to use Overleaf?

Comment: basically the paper is about Urdu language processing so i have to do it in any case... i have also tried it in MikTEX and same thing is happening there...

Comment: I have managed to get something working with `babel` and it's new bidi support. But it won't work on Overleaf and `babel`'s bidi support is only just starting to be developed. I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: I will be really grateful...

Comment: @tayyaba, I updated my solution.

Comment: Gives this error 

`LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \latinencoding already defined.`

Comment: @tayyaba, make sure MikTeX is fully updated in both user and admin mode. If it still gives the error, then I'm not sure :(. It's basically a hack because `acmart` force loads Type1 Libertine and Biolinum even for `xelatex` and `lualatex`. It compiles successfully for me on my reasonably up to date Debian testing machine with the standard Debian texlive packages (version 2017.20180110-1) .

Comment: it worked with your help i am posting my code in the answer thank you so much you really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

This solution works correctly:

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\let\latinencoding\relax
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import=ur]{urdu}
\babelprovide[import=en-US,default]{american}
\babelfont{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont{sf}{Linux Biolinum O}
\babelfont[urdu]{rm}{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\babelfont[urdu]{sf}{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\makeatletter
% fix mweights package bold font selection for using fontspec
\def\bfseries@rm{bx}
\def\bfseries@sf{bx}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\acmJournal{TWEB}
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmDOI{0000001.0000001}
\title{Article Title}
\author{John Doe}
\email{john.doe@example.com}
\begin{abstract}
 Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Article body starts here}

English paragraph with inline Urdu
\foreignlanguage{urdu}{اُردُو}
English text.

Display maths:

\[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sin n\phi \]

Right to left Urdu paragraph with inline English:

\selectlanguage{urdu}

اُردُو \foreignlanguage{american}{English text} اُردُو

\selectlanguage{american}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: You will *not* get correct output without the `bidi=default` option for `babel`. Test it with an Urdu sentence and paragraph.

Comment: actually i only need single Urdu words. sentences and paragraphs are not needed.

Comment: OK. You must also use the `no-math` option for `fontspec` otherwise you will get wrong fonts (for numbers at least) in equations.

Comment: Right. thank you :) i am checking other sections of the document now so far it is going fine.

Comment: If you have trouble, try my updated answer which is less intrusive in it's font adjustment.