# acmart abstract disappears by using package 'polyglossia'

Tags: polyglossia, right-to-left

When i include the package \usepackage{polyglossia} the abstract disappears.I want to write Urdu language in-between English lines. Urdu appears fine but the abstarct is gone. This is my code.

```
   \documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{urdu}
    \newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq} %for writing Urdu language

    \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}

    \begin{document}
   \title{Some title}
   \begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here..
   \end{abstract}
   \keywords{Some keywords}

   \maketitle

   \section{Introduction}
    Some text here \texturdu{اردو الفاظ} Some more text.

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this question relates to your earlier question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413398/write-urdu-language-in-acm-template)? What did you try, what kind of Urdu text do you need (single words or paragraphs), which (combinations of) language-related packages do you want to use?

Comment: That methods writes the word in opposite direction like if i give an example of English language it writes the sentence "this is a book" as "book a is this". It is ok in case of single words but incorrect for sentences. (and i am talking about Urdu language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `bidi.sty` seizes the initiative and changes `\maketitle` to mean a completely different thing.

You can save the meaning before `bidi` enters the scene and restore it after the package has done its job.

```
\documentclass[
  format=acmsmall,
  review=false,
  screen=true,
]{acmart}

\let\acmmaketitle\maketitle

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}

\newfontfamily\urdufont{Scheherazade}[
  Script=Arabic,
  Language=Urdu,
  %Scale=1.5,
]

\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\acmmaketitle}

\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{Some title}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here..
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Some keywords}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some text here \texturdu{اردو الفاظ} Some more text.

\end{document}
```

For producing the example I used Scheherazade because I don't have your font for Urdu. Just use the font you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. Thank you very much.